# Is My Approach to Get Unique Page Views, Efficent?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following way to count the unique page views in php webpage

```
$page_id = 33;  // unique page id
if(!isset($_SESSION[$page_id]))
{
   $_SESSION[$page_id] = 0;
}


if($_SESSION[$page_id]==0)
{
  $qry = "UPDATE tbl_threads SET views = (views + 1)";
  $_SESSION[$page_id] = 1;
}
```

Please tell me that Am I using the efficient and elegent way to count unique page views.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the most efficient way to do this with style.
Thank you.

Comment: This has to be the most comical answer I've read today!! You did exactly what the questioner asked you to do!